# How do I get kivy installed in a Pycharm Virtualenv?

Tags: python, pycharm, kivy

I am running Pycharm under Ubuntu and am trying to get Kivy installed in my project (virtualenv).  I followed the Kivy instructions but those install it in the default environment.  So, at my terminal prompt when I go into python I am able to successfully "import kivy".  However, when I am in a Pycharm project with virtualenv, I get an error when I try to import from the Python console:

```
import kivy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/mnt/bigdisk/apps/pycharm-2017.3.4/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 20, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
ImportError: No module named kivy
```

I've even tried activating the virtualenv in my terminal and then performing the installation instructions.  When I do this, I am told it is already installed.  I think this is happening because to install kivy you have to make a sudo call (sudo apt-get install python-kivy) which is resetting the environment.  I even tried sudoing to bash activating the environment and installing python-kivy, but again, it said it was installed.  How do I get Kivy installed in my Pycharm virtual environment?

Answer (score 4):

## Kivy Virtual Environment Installation using PyCharm

### Assumption

Assuming *virtualenv* or/and *virtualenvwrapper* already installed.

```
sudo pip install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper
```

### Launch PyCharm

1. Click ***Congfigure***
2. Click ***Settings***
3. Click ***project Interpreter***
4. Click *cogwheel* next to the ***Project Interpreter*** field, and choose the option ***Add...***
5. ***New environment*** is the default selection.
6. Type ***kivyinstall*** for the Location e.g. `/home/iam/.virtualenvs/kivyinstall`
7. Select ***Base interpreter*** e.g. Python 3.5, or Python 2.7 from the drop down list.
8. Do not select the ***Inherit global site-packages*** check-box.
9. Select the ***Make available to all projects*** check-box, if needed.
10. Click ***OK*** button
11. After *pip* and *setuptools* installed, click **+** beside the column heading, ***Latest***.
12. Type ***cython*** in the *search text input box* under **Available Packages** Dialog.
13. Select ***Specify version*** check-box to load version 0.25.2 which is compatible to Kivy version 1.10.0
14. Click ***Install Package*** button.
15. After cython 0.25.2 version installed successfully, type ***kivy*** in the *search text input box* under **Available Packages** Dialog.
16. Click ***Install Package*** button.
17. After kivy installed successfully, create a new project.
18. In your opened new project, if ***kivyinstall*** did not appear in the expanded ***External Libraries*** then click ***File*** » ***Settings...*** »  ***Project Interpreter*** and select Python...(kivyinstall) e.g. *Python 3.5 (kivyinstall)*

## Print Screens

[image: Img01 - Click cogwheel and select Add...]
[image: Img02 - Create virtualenv kivyinstall]
[image: Img03 - Virtualenv kivyinstall created and Python3.5]
[image: Img04 - Click + to install packages]
[image: Img05 - Install Cython verion 0.25.2]
[image: Img06 - Cython installed]
[image: Img07 - Install kivy]
[image: Img08 - Kivy installed]
[image: Img09 - Hello world Kivy App]

Comment: Well, I did all of this, but Kivy still doesn't install and still no errors.  The Kivy-Garden package is there along with other packages, but no "Kivy" package listed for the "kivyinstall" interpreter that I set up.

Comment: What was the Cython version installed?

Comment: I believed that Kivy was not installed because the Cython version installed is not compatible with Kivy. Please remove it and install Cython version 0.25.2 and then install Kivy.

Comment: @ikolim This is the best answer and worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

`apt-get install python-kivy` installs `kivy` for a system interpreter and not inside a virtualenv no matter what `sudo` tricks you did. There's a special paragraph in the official docs for installing `kivy` inside a virtualenv: https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-linux.html#installation-in-a-virtual-environment