# Failed to install package "kivy" (pycharm)

Tags: python, pycharm, kivy

Cannot add kivy to my pycharm project. I had been getting different types of errors and I fixed them but now it seems like I'm stuck.

When I click on "Kivy" and "Install Package" the process lasts for like 4 minutes and then fails with:

```
/tmp/pycharm-packaging/Kivy/kivy/graphics/svg.c:1:2: error: #error Do not use this file, it is the result of a failed Cython compilation.
```

I tried both installing via repository and using pip install. I updated python-dev, setuptools, pip and cython but nothing helps.

What else should I try?

Comment: Which version of Cython are you using?

Comment: @ikolim 0.28.3
(comments must be at least 15 characters in length so I had to add this line)

Comment: Cython version 0.25.2 is working with Kivy version 1.10.0. Down garde Cython to 0.25.2 and re-install Kivy.

Comment: Is it working now? If you want to install Kivy Virtual Environment, please refer to [Kivy Virtual Environment Installation using PyCharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49971489/how-do-i-get-kivy-installed-in-a-pycharm-virtualenv/49986714#49986714)

Comment: @ikolim I did it and pycharm still doesn’t want to install the package

Comment: Are you still getting the same error? What is the operating system and Python version are you using?

Comment: @ikolim I still have this error but I just installed kivy on a separate environment and it works perfect. Thank you so much!